# Wudu invalid or not?

Tags: wudu

**What happened:**

So, I did ghusl because I needed to, but then my towel touched my private parts, but I did not touch it. However, I then used the towel to dry the rest of my body. Wudu invalid?

Comment: According to the Hanafi Madhhab, touching private parts doesn't invalidate wudhu. However, according to Shafii' madhhab, it does. As in this case, you didn't touch your private parts rather the towel which was in contact with the private parts, your wudhu is still valid.

Comment: Even though the towel touched the rest of my body. Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: Please explain: You ask whether your wudu' is invalid while you performed ghusl. This really needs more input.